# How to reduce tabular column margin or is there whole alternativ?

Tags: tables

I want to demonstrate a number of transformations from one eigenstate to the other in one line:

[image: Here is a rendered screenshot of the current solution]

At the moment I am using a `tabular` with the code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[german, english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{orange}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{13}{c}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\floatsep}{0pt}
&$\mathds 1$&&$G_\text L^H$&&$\mathcal U^{6\times 6}$&&$\left(\mathcal U^{6\times 6}\right)^\dagger$&&$\left(G_\text L^H\right)^\dagger$&&$\mathds 1$\\
$e_\text L$ &$\longrightarrow$ & $e_\text L$ & $\longrightarrow$ & $\nu_\text R$ & $\longrightarrow$ & $u_\text R +u_\text L^C$  & $\longrightarrow$ & $\nu_\text R+\cancel{\nu_\text L^C}$ & $\longrightarrow$ & $e_\text L$ & $\longrightarrow$ & $e_\text L$\\
ma.&&fla.&&fla.&&mass&&flavour&&fla.&&mass\\
es.&&es.&&es.&&eigens.&&eigens.&&es.&&eigens.
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Has anyone an idea, how to make a better looking result? Is a `tabular` the correct Container? And if so: How can I make the margin between the columns are smaller such taht I do not need to abbreviate the Labels at the bottom of every second column? My problem is that the line is too wide now.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: you are setting `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\floatsep}{0pt}` in the first cell of the table where they have no effect at all.

Comment: You might find that `\makebox[0pt][c]{label}` comes in handy here, in order to hide the width of some of your labels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd) here:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\textCD}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}%
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=-0.5ex, column sep=2.11em]
    e_\mathrm{L}\rar{\mathds{1}_{\phantom{\mathrm{L}}}} & 
    e_\mathrm{L}\rar{G_\mathrm{L}^H} & 
    \nu_\mathrm{R}\rar{\mathcal{U}_{\phantom{\mathrm{L}}}^{6\times 6}} & 
    u_\mathrm{R} + u_\mathrm{L}^C\rar{(\mathcal U_{\phantom{\mathrm{L}}}^{6\times 6})^\dagger} & 
    \nu_\mathrm{R} +\cancel{\nu_\mathrm{L}^C}\rar{(G_\text L^H)^\dagger} & 
    e_\mathrm{L}\rar{\mathds{1}_{\phantom{\mathrm{L}}}} & 
    e_\mathrm{L}\\
    \textCD{ma.\\es.} &
    \textCD{fla.\\es.} &
    \textCD{fla.\\es.} &
    \textCD{mass\\eigens.} &
    \textCD{flavour\\eigens.} &
    \textCD{fla.\\es.} &
    \textCD{mass\\eigens.}\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can that with a simple `alignat`. I also use the `tabstackengine` package and `mathtools` to define a variant of `\xrightarrow` with a predefined length (default: 2em). I also define a `\particle` command with two arguments. If the text under the particle is too wide, you can use `\clap` from mathtools to prevent unwanted gaps between arrows and particle names:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\setstackgap{L}{3ex}%{0.9\baselineskip}

\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{orange}}

\newcommand\mylongrightarrow[2][2em]{{}\xrightarrow[\hskip#1]{\mathclap{#2}}{}}
 \newcommand\particle[2]{\Longunderstack{\ensuremath{#1}\\#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{7}
  \particle{e_{\mkern1mu\mathrm L}}{ma.\\es.}& \mylongrightarrow{\mathds 1} & \particle{e_{\mkern1mu\mathrm L}}{fla. \\es.}& \mylongrightarrow{G_{\mathrm L}^H} & \particle{ν_{\mkern1mu\mathrm R}}{fla.\\es.}& \mylongrightarrow{\mathcal U^{6 × 6}} & \particle{u_{\mkern1mu\mathrm R} + u_{\mathrm L}^{C}}{mass\\eigens.}
  & \mylongrightarrow[3em]{(\mathcal U^{6 × 6})^\dagger}
  & \particle{ν_{\mkern1mu\mathrm R} + \cancel{ν_{\mathrm L}^{C}}}{flavour\\eigens.}
  & \mylongrightarrow{(G_{\mathrm L}^H)^\dagger}
  & \particle{e_{\mkern1mu\mathrm L}}{fla.\\es.}
  & \mylongrightarrow{\mathds 1} &
  & \particle{e_{\mkern1mu\mathrm L}}{\clap{mass}\\\clap{eigens.}}![enter image description here][1]
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My Problem is, that the labels under the particles take horizontal space. With that there might be huge gaps between the particle symbol and the arrows.

Comment: @Matthias: I've changed and simplified my code. To prevent gaps, you can use the `\clap` command from `mathtools` (see example in my updated answer).